# fullCalendar angular2 height parent

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I use  angular2-fullcalendar. 
I try to set the height to 'parent'. And the parent is a div. Doesn't work ... the nav bar is show but not the calendar

[image]

**my html**

```
<div style="height: 20%" >
  <angular2-fullcalendar id="myCalendar"  [options]="calendarOptions"></angular2-fullcalendar>
</div>
```

Can you help me ? Thx for in advance !

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Comment `height: 'parent'` in the `calendarOptions`, so see the calendar.